# Cast Spark dataframe existing schema at once

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a dataframe that all of its columns are of String type, and I have a schema that contains the wanted type for each column. Is there any way of inserting the conversion into a one big try/ catch clause and covert the whole schema dynamically at once? The only solution I've seen is to handle each column specifically and convert its type.

Comment: How the target schema is represented? As map or something else?

Comment: As a StructType

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
val newDf = sparkSession.createDataFrame(oldDf.rdd, schema)
```

Comment: I get an exception 

```RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.String is not a valid external type for schema of int
Caused by: RuntimeException: java.lang.String is not a valid external type for schema of int```

Comment: @OferHelman It is because the actual data of `oldDf` is not compatible with the provided schema - one of the columns are of the source dataframe is of type String but you try to apply int type on it.