# map function on StructType in PySpark

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, struct

I have a StructType as follows:

```py
to_Schema = StructType([StructField('name', StringType(), True),
           StructField('sales', IntegerType(), True)])
```

The `dataframe_1` has both fields as StringType. So I created the above StructType so that I could use it to typecast the fields in `dataframe_1`.

I am able to do it in Scala:

```scala
val df2 = dataframe_1.selectExpr(to_Schema.map(
  col => s"CAST ( ${col.name} As ${col.dataType.sql}) ${col.name}"
): _*)
```

I am not able to use the same `map` function in python as StructType has no `map` function.

I've tried using `for` loop but it doesn't work as expected.

I am looking for a PySpark equivalent of the above Scala code.

Answer (score 2):

The below code will achieve the same thing in python:

```py
for s in to_Schema:
    df = df.withColumn(s.name, df[s.name].cast(s.dataType))
```

You can also create a new dataframe from the old one using the new schema as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69794141/19261326) answer:

```py
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(dataframe_1.rdd, to_Schema)
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be the direct translation:

```py
df2 = dataframe_1.selectExpr(*[f"CAST ({c.name} AS {c.dataType.simpleString()}) {c.name}" for c in to_Schema])
```

It could be simplified:

```py
df2 = dataframe_1.select([col(c.name).cast(c.dataType).alias(c.name) for c in to_Schema])
```

However, I like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73263707#73265372) answer more ;)